# BigQuery: Create JSON object with key from column

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create JSON object with the new JSON data type in BigQuery, where the key is not the name of the column but instead the value within the column. So for example, for the following query

```sql
select key, value from unnest(array<struct<key string, value int64>>[("a", 1), ("b", 2)])
```

I would like to have a JSON that looks like

```sql
-- {"a": 1}
-- {"b": 2}
```

The query below doesn't work (`Invalid JSON literal: syntax error while parsing object key - invalid literal; last read: '{k'; expected string literal at [1:8]` )

```sql
select json '{key, value}' from unnest(array<struct<key string, value int64>>[("a", 1), ("b", 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here. The first one if you need a new structure:

```
select struct(data.key, data.value) as new_struct 
from unnest(array<struct<key string, value int64>>[("a", 1), ("b", 2)]) data
```

| new_struct.key | new_struct.value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |

The second option is to use `TO_JSON_STRING`:

```
select TO_JSON_STRING(data) as new_string
from unnest(array<struct<key string, value int64>>[("a", 1), ("b", 2)]) data
```

| new_string |
| --- |
| {"key":"a","value":1} |
| {"key":"b","value":2} |

The third option is to create a your own string:

```
select '{"' || data.key ||'":'|| data.value || '}' as new_string 
from  unnest(array<struct<key string, value int64>>[("a", 1), ("b", 2)]) data
```

| new_string |
| --- |
| {"a":1} |
| {"b":2} |

Answer (score 1):

For your question it seems like you are looking into Bigquery Json response instead of Bigquery Results.

If that is the requirement then you can try to use Pivot to send the `Key` row to the header. However you have to know all the keys that are present in the data set beforehand.

`Query:`

```
select * from (
 select key, value from unnest(array<struct<key string, value int64>>[("a", 1), ("b", 2)])
)
pivot
(
 max(value) for Key in('a','b')
)p
```

`Results View:`

[image]

`JSON View:`

[image]

If you don’t know the keys beforehand then you have to create a dynamic query for that.

Another way is to create a consolidated column using String concatenation (same as 3rd option of  vampire1234’s answer )